# Remove the ?vietnam% extra string on URL

Tags: url, parameters

I have several links that duplicate the homepage. For example:
https://www.gameressential.com/?vietnam/2022-09-18102366_html

Also,

https://www.gameressential.com/?vn/2022-09-18122558_html

I wanted to permanently remove the `/?vn/2022-09-18122558_html` and `/?vietnam/2022-09-18102366_html` so that it will not show as an issue in Google search console. I already checked the htaccess and no codes added there. I tried to redirect but it is just a temporary solution. I need the permanent solution.

Comment: Did you checked your sitemap?

Comment: If your issue is search engines, consider working with a `robots.txt` file. You can check googles official documentation here [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/intro)

Comment: I checked the robots file and no special in there https://www.gameressential.com/robots.txt

Comment: @GicuAftene yes, eveything is fine here https://www.gameressential.com/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: Probably you should ask for removal if you don't want to consider the "permanent redirection" ... in my opinion redirection is the best solution in order to maintain these old indexed urls

Comment: @GicuAftene but I think there is a code here that generates this slug. if I will redirect this, shoudl I do it in htaccess? can you help me with the code? Also another slug here https://www.gameressential.com/index.php?dxdxcnlic1338/. which still shows homepage

Comment: in your .htaccess add, for each url, a line like this.                                                `Redirect 301 <the url to redirect> <destination>`

Comment: `Redirect 301 <the url to redirect> <destination>`

Comment: Without the '<>' brackets

Comment: but this urls are so many. maybe thousands

Comment: Btw insert these lines after the opening <IfModule> tag.

Comment: I can't do it one by one. is it possible to remove the extra parameters? like after /?.

Comment: Yes with a proper Rewrite condition.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. I used rank math.